# Entering digitizing mode makes QGIS freeze

Tags: qgis, editing, snapping

When I toggle the editing mode QGIS freezes. The layer is stored in PostGIS.
I'm using QGIS 3.10.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the snapping option (Project >  snapping options) was set to "all layers". One of the vector layer is an *ESRI ArcGIS Feature Server*. QGIS tries to create an index on this huge layer, it is the indexing which makes QGIS freeze.

**Solution**
Disable the snapping or avoid the snapping on this layer.